# Facebook - How to make the authorization dialog open in a popup?

Tags: facebook, popup

I have the following code:

```
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => 'id',
      'secret' => 'secret',
    ));

    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    if ($user) {
      $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    } else {
      $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'req_perms' => 'email,user_birthday,user_about_me'
      ));
    }
```

and HTML:

```
 <a class="button-fb" href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>" title="Connect with Facebook">Connect with Facebook</a>
```

The problem is that the `<a>` will open in the current page, I want to open in a popup (like most site do). How to do? =)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this snippet to create a popup.. It uses Javascript.

```
<a class="button-fb" href="javascript: void(0)" 
   onclick="window.open('<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>', 
  'windowname1', 
  'width=200, height=77'); 
   return false;" title="Connect with Facebook">Connect with Facebook</a>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the facebook redirect doesnt return do the "parent" frame.